# group by in rails return strange data

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to apply group active record command in rails rest api, however my database is in MySql.

When I query without group by I get correct data but when I use group on the same query I get strange data collection. I am using group to decrease query time coz in original it takes alot of time to retrieve data from database

Here is my original query

```
Records.owned_by(User.find_by_email(params[:user].to_s).id).where(device_id: params[:did]).includes(:record_students, :record_employees, :record_admins, :record_others)
```

but when I use group to increase the efficiency the returned data set is not valid

here is my new query with group

```
Records.owned_by(User.find_by_email(params[:user].to_s).id).where(device_id: params[:did]).includes(:record_students, :record_employees, :record_admins, :record_others).group("date(created_at)")
```

any idea what is wrong. Thanks

Comment: Could you please define "strange"? Perhaps with an example...

Comment: Hi, I figured out the problem, I was wrong in the sense of understanding meaning of Group by, but now it is fine, I have another question if you are ok, my queries talking 6 second to fetch 25000 records from database in which each record in 1 kb of size. do you think it can be improved....? I guess yes...

Comment: It depends upon the query, but I am supposing that when you say your query takes 6 seconds, it might actually be executing several queries "under the hood" (you can tell by looking at the console output). This happens many times with relations in Rails. One resolution to that is to condense the multiple queries into fewer or a single query. Without concrete examples, it's hard to provide more input than that.

Comment: thanks, but lets say I only have the query that I have mentioned in my question, without group by , if this query takes 6 second for 25000 records I guess it is not efficient. I am talking everything in Development envirnoment...do you think this query can be improved...?

Comment: What does the generated SQL look like?